# DVC | Permission denied ERROR: failed to reproduce stage: failed to run: .py, exited with 126

Tags: python-3.x, permission-denied, dvc

Goal: run `.py` files via. `dvc.yaml`.

There are stages before it, in `dvc.yaml`, that don't produce the error.

`dvc exp run`:

```
(venv) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ dvc exp run
Stage 'inference' didn't change, skipping
Running stage 'load_data':
> load_data.py
/bin/bash: line 1: load_data.py: Permission denied
ERROR: failed to reproduce 'load_data': failed to run: load_data.py, exited with 126
```

`dvc repro`:

```
(venv) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ dvc repro
Stage 'predict' didn't change, skipping                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Stage 'evaluate' didn't change, skipping
Stage 'inference' didn't change, skipping
Running stage 'load_data':
> load_data.py
/bin/bash: line 1: load_data.py: Permission denied
ERROR: failed to reproduce 'load_data': failed to run: pdl1_lung_model/load_data.py, exited with 126
```

---

`dvc doctor`:

```
DVC version: 2.10.2 (pip)
---------------------------------
Platform: Python 3.9.12 on Linux-5.15.0-46-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
Supports:
        webhdfs (fsspec = 2022.5.0),
        http (aiohttp = 3.8.1, aiohttp-retry = 2.5.2),
        https (aiohttp = 3.8.1, aiohttp-retry = 2.5.2),
        s3 (s3fs = 2022.5.0, boto3 = 1.21.21)
Cache types: hardlink, symlink
Cache directory: ext4 on /dev/nvme0n1p5
Caches: local
Remotes: s3
Workspace directory: ext4 on /dev/nvme0n1p5
Repo: dvc, git
```

`dvc exp run -v`:

[output.txt](https://gist.github.com/danielbellsa/3f2fe05c1535d494a8677e54cddf684a)

`dvc exp run -vv`:

[output2.txt](https://gist.github.com/danielbellsa/a124cf28b3f0252556deb90b042b7cec)

Comment: The only other reference to this error at this time: [source](https://githublab.com/repository/issues/munichpavel/risk-ai-workshop/8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1

`.py` files weren't running as scripts.

They need to be; if you want to run one `.py` file per `stage` in `dvc.yaml`.

To do so, you want to append **Boiler-plate code**, at the bottom of each `.py` file.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # invoke primary function() in .py file, w/ params
```

#### Solution 2

```
chmod 777 ....py
```

#### Soution 3

I forgot the `python` in `cmd:`

```
  load_data:
    cmd: python pdl1_lung_model/load_data.py
```